# Table name with special characters in Omnis database file

Tags: sql, odbc, bids

I have a very old Omnis database I'm trying to copy data over to SQL server using BIDS. I'm using ODBC driver provided by Omnis which works fine for all the tables except for few tables whose name have special characters example OMNIS.F-ABCD. I have tried formating my SQL statements in many ways as shown below and none of them have worked.

```
SELECT * FROM OMNIS.F-ABCD
SELECT * FROM [OMNIS.F-ABCD]
SELECT * FROM 'OMNIS.F-ABCD'
SELECT * FROM "OMNIS.F-ABCD"
```

Every time I get an error message saying

```
ODBC--Call failed.
Syntax error in SQL statement (#0)
```

I have tried using Linked Table in Microsoft Access, SQL Server management studio, C# code but none of them worked. Has anyone ran into this kind of situation?

Comment: have you tried SELECT * FROM OMNIS.[F-ABCD]?

Comment: Yes. I have tried [OMNIS].[F-ABCD], OMNIS.[F-ABCD], OMNIS.'F-ABCD' and OMNIS."F-ABCD" and none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using something like \ to see if that would work:

```
SELECT * FROM OMNIS.F\-ABCD
```